# Customizing the markitUp Toolbar

Tags: javascript, markitup

Has anyone figured out how to truely customize the [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) toolbar? Sure you can remove items from the mySettings config variable but that somehow garbles the toolbar. You end up with the right toolbar items represented by the wrong buttons. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem.
I have found this tutorial (french) that help me to customize the toolbar
[jaysalvat.com](http://blog.jaysalvat.com/articles/markitup-part-I-installation-et-personnalisation.php)

When creating the new toolbar in the CSS the number in the button name (class) seems important.

markItUpButton1
markItUpButton2
markItUpButton3
markItUpButton4

In CSS if you don't want a button that is associate to markItUpButton2 remove it or comment it 
and you will have to rename the next markItUpButton3  to  markItUpButton2 and so on or change the image associate to it.

The best way it is to start from scratch using the tutorial.

I may be wrong but in my case following the tutorial and the number logic fixed the problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I've found it pretty easy to add my own buttons to the toolbar.. just add the className: 'name of class' in with the options/ mySettings config.. example is below for the bold tag

```
{name:'Bold', key:'B', className: 'pBold', openWith:'(!(<strong>|!|<b>)!)', closeWith:'(!(</strong>|!|</b>)!)' },
```

then in my stylesheet I do

```
.markItUp .pBold a {
background-image:url(images/bold.png);
}
```

Comment: this is the best solution.  Add the className in set.js, and set the css of className in style.css

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, I think it's very easy. You can just set the buttons to display:none in style.css, and comment out the separators in settings.js

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same problem. Sad, but markitup ties button image to it's order number in header. 
The only thing you can do is edit both markitupSettings json and css styles file.