# markitup settings issue

Tags: jquery, textile, markitup

Here is my settings in set.js. I basically don't want the H1 - H3 tags, images etc. So I deleted those lines but my markitup text area appears to not like the settings and shows up like following. I am using the textile set with a basic simple skin.

Also, is there a sprited version of the images?

[image]

```
mySettings = {
    previewParserPath:  '', // path to your Textile parser
    onShiftEnter:       {keepDefault:false, replaceWith:'\n\n'},
    markupSet: [
        {name:'Heading 4', key:'4', openWith:'h4(!(([![Class]!]))!). ', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
        {name:'Heading 5', key:'5', openWith:'h5(!(([![Class]!]))!). ', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
        {name:'Heading 6', key:'6', openWith:'h6(!(([![Class]!]))!). ', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
        {name:'Paragraph', key:'P', openWith:'p(!(([![Class]!]))!). '},
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Bold', key:'B', closeWith:'*', openWith:'*'},
        {name:'Italic', key:'I', closeWith:'_', openWith:'_'},
        {name:'Stroke through', key:'S', closeWith:'-', openWith:'-'},
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Bulleted list', openWith:'(!(* |!|*)!)'},
        {name:'Numeric list', openWith:'(!(# |!|#)!)'}, 
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Link', openWith:'"', closeWith:'([![Title]!])":[![Link:!:http://]!]', placeHolder:'Your text to link here...' },
        {separator:'---------------' },
        {name:'Quotes', openWith:'bq(!(([![Class]!]))!). '}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have actually deleted the buttons, only image backgrounds remained. You have to edit css too:

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------
// markItUp!
// By Jay Salvat - http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/
// ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

}
.textile .markItUpButton1 a {
    background-image:url(images/h4.png); 
}
.textile .markItUpButton2 a {
    background-image:url(images/h5.png); 
}
.textile .markItUpButton3 a {
    background-image:url(images/h6.png); 
}
.textile .markItUpButton4 a {
    background-image:url(images/paragraph.png); 
}

.textile .markItUpButton5 a {
    background-image:url(images/bold.png);
}
.textile .markItUpButton6 a {
    background-image:url(images/italic.png);
}
.textile .markItUpButton7 a {
    background-image:url(images/stroke.png);
}

.textile .markItUpButton8 a {
    background-image:url(images/list-bullet.png);
}
.textile .markItUpButton9 a {
    background-image:url(images/list-numeric.png);
}

.textile .markItUpButton10 a {
    background-image:url(images/link.png);
}

.textile .markItUpButton11 a {
    background-image:url(images/quotes.png);
}
```

(original version: http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/textile/ )

No sprited version AFAIK, but you can create one by yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you just need to hide buttons in the CSS file (using `display: none;`). Don't modify the JS file to comment or remove items; you can just comment or remove separators

```
 {separator:'---------------' },
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to hide some buttons, what you should change is the CSS file but not the JS settings file.

```
.markItUp .markItUpButton1 a {
background-image:url(images/h1.png); 
display: none;}
```

Just set display: none is ok.

Comment: Not true - Markitup can work with multiple settings objects, which is how you should change the available buttons.

Comment: Unfortunately you actually have to do both.

The CSS has to be updated as well as the settings JS or you'll end up with mismatched buttons icons. The images in the CSS are numerically listed, not by name. There is [a walkthrough article](http://blog.jaysalvat.com/articles/markitup-part-I-installation-et-personnalisation.php) (French) that helps if you're unclear (via [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1804333/226756).)